# I want to autofill responses on an ms word form into a report template

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, templates, forms

In ms word 2010, I’d like to create a form which collects data using text fields and drop down menus and perhaps even some radio buttons. (ok that part I got)

But I then want to take the responses to the form and insert into a report template (later on in the same document). (even this I kinda get, e.g., using legacy tools and “calculate on exit”)

But the catch is I need to convert some of the responses to different text. Let me give you a for instance.

On the medical history form I have a question such as:

Do you have a history of heart disease (drop down menu with yes or no)

If the person selects "yes" then I want it to autofill into the report (later in the same word document) “the patient reported a history of heart disease, or if they select "no", “the patient denied a history of heart disease”

So I want to take the responses to some form content control objects and replace the text (yes=reported, no = denied) and insert into a place later in the document.

thanks